# Laravel route no input specified

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I'm building an api in `Laravel 5.2` I've put `angular2` in the public map.

But my routes in Laravel don't work anymore. I've installed `dingo` and `Jwt auth`. In my public folder I've setup angular 2 (that's reachable). When I go to for example `domain.dev/api/v1/` I expect to see `test`. (I've configured the prefix `api` in my `api.php` config file). But I see

> no input specified

In my `homestead.yaml` I've set the vhost to `/public` and I've added ip to `/etc/hosts`.

When I visit domain.dev I see my angular2 app. So why is my routes file not working anymore?

```
<?php

$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1',function($api)
{
    $api->group(['prefix' => 'v1'],function($api)
    {
        /*
         * Authentication
         */
        $controllerPath = 'App\Http\Controllers\api\v1\Authentication@';
        $api->post('/login', $controllerPath.'login');
        $api->get('/', function() {
            dd('test');
        });
    });

    $api->group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'jwt.auth'],function($api)
    {

    });
});
```

Thankyou